# Excel 2007 - Sheets.add from template file loses formatting

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have a template in Excel 2003 that copies in template sheets as needed.  We are about to upgrade to Excel 2007, and I have found that when the sheets are added as in the past:

```
Sheets.Add Type:="Z:\Investments.xltm"
```

The buttons on the sheet move around and it drops random cells formatting.  I am wondering if anyone else has encountered this.

Comment: Do you get the same button-moving and formatting issues if you just open the template from within Excel? Or is it just when you use the VBA code?

Comment: Good question.  It is fine if I open the template it is fine.  But if I pick insert worksheet from template (which is basically what my code is emulating), it does not work.  In fact, I get a message, 'Fixed objects will move.' that I do not get when I do it through code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try adding your template worksheet in a different way? Try:

```
Sub AddSheet()

    Application.Workbooks.Add "Z:\Investments.xltm"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

End Sub
```

This will create a new workbook based on the template, then copy the required worksheet to the calling workbook.

I'm just curious as to whether this makes a difference.

There is another option you may want to consider, if there's only one workbook that uses the template, is to have a hidden worksheet in your workbook and base new sheets on that.

Comment: Yes it did.  I had to throw in a line to activate the book I was copying into though as otherwise I was getting an application error. I have to add about 30 or so sheets this way (very dynamic template) so hopefully this does not slow it down.  Thanks!  What would life be like if you didn't have to work around Excel's shortcomings!

Comment: Just as an aside, I usually set a variable to point to the workbook I'm using, e.g.

dim wkbk as Workbook
set wkbk = ActiveWorkbook

or 

set wkbk = ThisWorkbook

Then I don't have to worry about which is the active workbook.

In my example above, I would also close the template workbook after I had copied the worksheet, adding the line
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
so that I didn't have to worry about it any more.

Getting Excel to do what I want is half the fun :)

Comment: Agreed I do the same as Excel does like to bite you in the butt if you make any assumptions about what the activebook, sheet or cell might be.

Comment: I did discover one downside to this approach. If you have a formula that is 255 chars or longer, adding sheets this way truncates those formulas whereas the sheets.add type= way does not do that.  The sad thing is now each way has a total showstopper downside (short of reworking all formulas over 255 chars)